# Selecting the files is not happening

Tags: java, io

I have this below program which is not selecting the files within specified period of time please update..whats wrong in  it ..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    public static String ITEM_TYPE_FILE = "File"; // for file

    public static String ITEM_TYPE_FOLDER = "Folder"; // for folder

    public static String ITEM_TYPE_FILE_AND_FOLDER = "FileAndFolder"; // for file and folder

    private Pattern fileNamePattern;

    public PatternFileFilter(Pattern fileNamePattern) {
        this.fileNamePattern = fileNamePattern;
    }

    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return fileNamePattern.matcher(pathname.getName()).find() || pathname.isDirectory();
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return fileNamePattern;
    }

    public static void searchFile(File topFolderOrFile, String type, PatternFileFilter filter, long timeOut) throws IOException {

        long startTimeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        if (topFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) {
            File[] subFoldersAndFileNames = topFolderOrFile.listFiles(filter);
            if (subFoldersAndFileNames != null && subFoldersAndFileNames.length > 0) {
                for (File subFolderOrFile : subFoldersAndFileNames) {
                    if (ITEM_TYPE_FILE.equals(type) && subFolderOrFile.isFile()) {
                        System.out.println("File name matched ----- " + subFolderOrFile.getName());
                    }
                    if (ITEM_TYPE_FOLDER.equals(type) && subFolderOrFile.isDirectory()
                            && filter.getPattern().matcher(subFolderOrFile.getName()).find()) {

                        System.out.println("Folder name matched ----- " + subFolderOrFile.getName());
                    }

                    if (ITEM_TYPE_FILE_AND_FOLDER.equals(type) && filter.getPattern().matcher(subFolderOrFile.getName()).find()) {
                        System.out.println("File or Folder name matched ----- " + subFolderOrFile.getName());

                    }
                    // You need to decide if you want to process the folders inline // or after you've processed the
                    // file list...
                    if (subFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) {
                        long timeElapsed = startTimeStamp - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        if (((timeOut * 1000) - timeElapsed) < 0) {
                            System.out.println("Could not complete operation-- timeout");
                        } else {
                            searchFile(subFolderOrFile, type, filter, (timeOut * 1000) - timeElapsed);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void searchFile(String topFolderName, String type, String fileNamePatternRegExp, long timeOut)
            throws IOException {
        File topFolderOrFile = new File(topFolderName);
        Pattern fileNamePattern = Pattern.compile(fileNamePatternRegExp);
        searchFile(topFolderOrFile, type, new PatternFileFilter(fileNamePattern), timeOut);
    }

    // ***************
    public static void main(String[] str) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Type Item to Search ");
        System.out.println("1 File");
        System.out.println("2 Folder ");
        System.out.println("3 Both");
        System.out.println("0 Exit");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String searchType = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter top folder name ::");

        String topFolderName = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter name of file to search ::");

        String fileName = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter timeout period in seconds::");

        String timeOutStr = br.readLine();

        if (searchType == null || fileName == null || topFolderName == null || timeOutStr == null) {
            throw new Exception("Error Occured::Provide both the input Parameters");
        }

        int searchTypeInd = Integer.parseInt(searchType);
        switch (searchTypeInd) {

        case 1:
            searchFile(topFolderName, ITEM_TYPE_FILE, fileName, Long.parseLong(timeOutStr));
            break;

        case 2:
            searchFile(topFolderName, ITEM_TYPE_FOLDER, fileName, Long.parseLong(timeOutStr));
            break;
        case 3:
            searchFile(topFolderName, ITEM_TYPE_FILE_AND_FOLDER, fileName, Long.parseLong(timeOutStr));
            break;

        case 0:
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Please advise if I have folder in D:\saral it should select the files from D: folder

> The result I am getting is ...
>
> Type Item to Search  1 File 2 Folder  3 Both 0 Exit 3 Enter top folder
>   name :: Test Enter name of file to search :: allMfile.txt Enter
>   timeout period in seconds:: 5

Comment: What diagnostics have you performed? Have you debugged it, added logging etc?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that anyone will bother wading through your code. Make a real effort at reducing that code down to the few lines that are relevant to the question. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more info on this concept

Comment: Also no need to show the entire code  that reveals which company you are working for (or which company libraries you are using )

Comment: @Andreas_D I said *unlikely*, not *impossible* :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is wrong:

```
searchFile(subFolderOrFile, type, filter, (timeOut * 1000) - timeElapsed);
                                                  ^^^^^^^
```

Looks like you mix time units: you expect seconds but pass a milliseconds value. In your case, the first timeout you pass is equal to 5 seconds, in the first recursion you pass 5000 seconds and 1000 times more in the next level...

Hint: rename the method parameter to `timeOutInSeconds` and read your code again.

Comment: could you please post the complete updated program as I have done

Comment: Sorry, no I can't/won't. Last hint: Delete `* 1000` from that line in your code. And you should rename the variable to `timeOutInSeconds` to avoid confusion about units.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to invert the logic. Instead of passing in a timeout (and doing complex calculations), calculate the end time outside the method:

```
long timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(timeOutStr);
```

In the method, you can check for a timeout using:

```
if( System.currentTimeMillis() > timeOut ) { break; }
```

You also don't end the loop in your code (using `break` or `return`) so the check for timeout just prevents the recursive call.

Lastly, consider inverting your `if()` conditions instead of nesting them:

```
if (!topFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) { return; }

File[] subFoldersAndFileNames = topFolderOrFile.listFiles(filter);
if (subFoldersAndFileNames == null || subFoldersAndFileNames.length == 0) { return; }

...
```

Comment: could you please post the complete updated program as I have done

Comment: Could you please try to understand my answer, first? If you don't understand it, you should probably take a beginners course in writing Java or ask someone with more Java knowledge to explain it to you.